# Why I can not upgrade to new git version in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have followed with steps [here](http://askmetutorials.blogspot.tw/2014/03/install-git-191-on-ubuntu-linuxmint.html) from the link, it supports git 1.9.1. My ubuntu is 13.04

Step 1: Add the Official PPA provided by GIT
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`

Step 2: Update the Repository
`sudo apt-get update`

Step 3: Install GIT 1.9.1
`sudo apt-get install git`

However, after I run `sudo apt-get install git`  I get below result.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.

And then
`git --version`
`git version 1.8.3.2`

It's still the old version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since this is not about programming it might be better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for askubuntu.com

Comment: Since `raring` is not supported anymore,the package for raring has been removed from the ppa `ppa:git-core/ppa`.Your best bet would be `saucy` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should keep in mind that Ubuntu 13.04 is now considered outdated and you'll never get more support or updates for that.

Second Ubuntu software channel usually keeps behind the real versions since it works on the stability so it doesn't update to the latest version. so to do that you have to add a third party repository as you have did, but as the output this means either the new repository does't contain the needed version